# How to hide inherited public variables in the inspector?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, attributes

I have 2 classes A and B, Class B inherits from Class A.

Let's say that Class A has a public int variable called Lives, and since Class B inherits from class A this variable (Lives) will show in the inspector.

I want to hide the variable (Lives) from class B in the inspector. A lot of people told me to just make the variable (Lives) private with a `[SerializeField]` attribute, but that doesn't work for me since a lot of cases I still want to access that variable from different scripts such as `GameManager` script when i'm using Class A.

Is there anyway I could do that? the closest I answer I can see is in this link [Hide Public Variables](https://forum.unity.com/threads/hiding-inherited-public-variable-in-the-inspector.161828/). "Look for the last comment".

Comment: If the assembly structure supports this, maybe internal is the droid you are looking for? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/internal

Comment: Or maybe your worry is about them overwriting/Hiding the variable? If so, sealing it can turn that off. It is really unclear why you would want this. It sounds like you got a XY problem, and hiding the variable is your Y.

Comment: you can also change it to a public property. as far as I remember public properties don't show up in inspector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe that you can hide a variable inherited from a base class by any easy means. If you really want a property to only show up in the base inspector, but be hidden in the inherited class inspector you probably need to write a custom inspector. I took the liberty of writing an editor script that allows you to hide properties in the inspector by name.

To apply it to your own inspector panel you can use the helper class I created.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System;

public static class EditorHelper
{
    public static List<SerializedProperty> GetExposedProperties(SerializedObject so, IEnumerable<string> namesToHide = null)
    {
        if (namesToHide == null) namesToHide = new string[] { };
        IEnumerable<FieldInfo> componentFields = so.targetObject.GetType().GetFields();
        List<SerializedProperty> exposedFields = new List<SerializedProperty>();

        foreach (FieldInfo info in componentFields)
        {
            bool displayInInspector = info.IsPublic && !Attribute.IsDefined(info, typeof(HideInInspector));
            displayInInspector = displayInInspector || (info.IsPrivate && Attribute.IsDefined(info, typeof(SerializeField)));
            displayInInspector = displayInInspector && !namesToHide.Contains(info.Name);

            if (displayInInspector){
                SerializedProperty prop = so.FindProperty(info.Name);
                if(prop != null)
                    exposedFields.Add(prop);
            }
        }

        return exposedFields;
    }
}
```

Then in your unity project create a folder called "Editor" and place this script inside it. The only changes that you need to make are changing "MyCustomScript" to the name of you class. Then in the OnEnable method modify the list of hidden properties to include the names of all the properties you want to be hidden.

```
using UnityEditor;
using System.Collections.Generic;


[CustomEditor(typeof(MyCustomScript))]
public class MyCustomScriptEditor : Editor
{
    private List<SerializedProperty> properties;

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        string[] hiddenProperties = new string[]{"SomeString2"}; //fields you do not want to show go here
        properties = EditorHelper.GetExposedProperties(this.serializedObject,hiddenProperties);
    }

    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        //base.OnInspectorGUI(); - (standard way to draw base inspector)

        //We draw only the properties we want to display here
        foreach (SerializedProperty property in properties)
        {
            EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(property,true);
        }
        serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for this great answer, but I copied the code from the link in the question and it worked fine. How can I learn these things? Custom inspector? Property drawers? I can't find a reliable source about such topics! I really want to learn them.

Comment: Glad to hear it. Yeah, the documentation for Editor scripting is a bit scattered. I learned over a long period by watching Unite presentations on youtube and reading the Unity manual. Here is a link to one of the talks if you're interested : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9bHzTDIJX_Q

Comment: As an alternative you may want to consider learning UIElements, the new UI framework Unity is switching to. A lot of the features are in preview, but it seems like an easier way to build custom UI in general. It seems to be much simpler and the same UI can be used in-game or in the inspector.